# Mongodb update not working on some keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my query to update document in mongodb.

```
campaignModel.update({campaignId:req.body.campaignId}, { "$set": {
        name:'super',status:'completed'
    }},{"multi":true},function(campaignSaveError, campaignSaveData){

 });
```

The problem is `status` is not updating but `name` field updates properly.

Here is the model defenition

```
let campaignSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        status:String
    }

);
```

Comment: Are there any errors ?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Looks like there is no error in Mongo query. Plz double check your record.

Comment: Already checked it but data not updated